# Set CURRENT PATH in jdbc url

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

To access the tables it was enough to add `currentSchema` parameter to the URL:

```
jdbc:db2://host:50000/dbname:currentSchema=schemaname;
```

But it doesn't work for stored procedures. Infocenter says I should set CURRENT PATH as well. Is it possible to set it in jdbc URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property name is `currentFunctionPath`:

```
jdbc:db2://host:50000/dbname:currentSchema=schemaname;currentFunctionPath=blah
```

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052607.html

Comment: Oh IBM...  
my value will be "blah, current_path"